# Element is not centered when it reaches max-width

Tags: html, css

I have an element in my HTML that has this style:

```
{
   max-width: 1500;
   padding-rigth: 40px;
   padding-left: 40px;
   width: auto;
}
```

when the screen is less than 1580px everything is ok and the element is centered in the screen, but when the screen goes larger than that the element is not centered and sticks to the right of screen(with a 40px padding).

what can I do to center the element when the screen is larger than 1580px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when the screen is less than 1580px everything is ok and the element is centered in the screen

I assume that the element is a block-level element, right? If so you just need to give a `margin-left`/`margin-right` of `auto` to achieve the alignment.

```css
{
   max-width: 1500;
   padding-rigth: 40px;
   padding-left: 40px;
   width: auto;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Only if the parent spans on 100% and has position set to relative.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu The statement I quoted proves that the wrapper element is a block-level element as well — having a full-width of the window or its parent.

Comment: I have debugged code where people didn't understand why some child doesn't behave as they wanted to and upon inspection it turned out there was a wrapper between the child and the full-width parent. It happens to beginners, so I thought it should be clearly specified, for clarity and completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Add margin: 0 auto;

```
  {
   max-width: 1500;
   padding-rigth: 40px;
   padding-left: 40px;
   width: auto;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `margin: 0 auto;`. In this example, the `#center` div will expand up to 1500px, then stay centered inside its parent `div`:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div id="center"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#center {
   max-width: 1500px;
   margin: 0 auto
   width: auto;
}
```

Note, if you want to specify your values, you should really assign a unit of measurement so the browser knows how to handle it, i.e. `1500px` rather than just `1500`. Also, `padding-rigth` looks like a typo, and won't do anyting anyway as it's not a valid CSS property :)